# Countdown timer does not stop even after cancel

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, countdowntimer

This is how i am using `CountdownTimer` in my application

I am calling it from `Fragment`

```
CounterClass counterClass=CounterClass.getInstance(180000,1000);
counterClass.setTextView(tvTimer);
counterClass.setContext(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
counterClass.start();
```

and when user presses back button from activity, i use this code

```
CounterClass.getInstance().cancel();
CounterClass.getInstance().onFinish();
```

but this is not helping, I have added a `Log` message in `onTick`, i can see the tick continuously working even after `cancel` is called.

This is my implementation of `CountDownTimer`

```
public  class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {


     public static CounterClass getInstance(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval){
        instance = new CounterClass(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        return instance;
    }



@Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long millis= millisUntilFinished;
        elapsedTime = millisUntilFinished;

        String hms= String.format("%02d:%02d",
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes( millisUntilFinished),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));
        tvTimer.setText(hms);

}

}
```

Kindly guide me how stop and reset timer. I have also tried `boolean` approach, where i set and checked boolean in `onTick`, but that also didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new instance of your counter class upon each call to `getInstance()`. For this singleton pattern, you will want to return the same instance each time. What is happening now is that you are cancelling a new instance while the old instance continues to run. You will need to make a mod to your code something like this:

```
public  class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

     private static CounterClass sInstance;

     public static CounterClass getInstance(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval){
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new CounterClass(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }
        return sInstance;
    }
    ...
```

You also probably don't need to call `onFinish()` yourself and should let the framework do that for you.